# При использовании FaceBook SDK получаю ошибку

Tags: android

При использовании FaceBook SDK получаю ошибку

В первый раз когда запускаю работает номально. После 1 раза ошибка. invalid key sha.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            String userId = loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId();
            String accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken();

            Log.e("AAAAA=onSuccess", userId + "  " + accessToken+"   "+profile.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

Как быть? Что ему нужно. Я ключ debug.key использовал

Answer (score 1):

Лучшим решением в подобной ситуации для меня стало пересоздание проекта в Facebook Developer Console. Причем скорее всего оно показывает в ошибке не ваш ключ. Можете попробовать  сделать LogOut  в Приложении Facebook  и потом попробовать заново залогиниться в своем приложении, либо вообще попробуйте удалить приложение Facebook. Возможно это не лучший вариант, но для меня сработал.

Comment: Все верно ключ не мой. И что мне каждый раз щяс это делать чтоли?

Comment: Ну я пересоздал проект в  faceebook console   - один раз, после этого вроде подобная ошибка не появлялась!

Comment: Это не так сложно, просто пересоздайте проект, потом заменить fb_app_id  в вашем приложении и протестите, у меня это заняло 5 минут!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сгенерировать валидный ключ, для этого выполните следующие шаги

1) Скачайте Openssl [отсюда](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads).

2) Создайте папку **openssl** на диске **C**

3) Извлеките скачанный файл в созданную папку на диске **С**

4) Скопируйте файл **debug.keystore** из папки **.android **(C:\Users\SYSTEM.android) и вставьте её в папку JDK\bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk{версия}\bin)

5) **Откройте cmd.exe** и перейдите по пути к папке JSK\bin (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk{версия}\bin).

6) Вставьте этот код и нажмите Enter

> keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore c:\openssl\bin\debug.txt

7) Теперь вы должны **ввести пароль**, пароль = **android**

8) Если вы посмотрите в папке **openssl\bin**, вы найдете там файл **debug.txt**

9) Теперь вы можете перезапустить cmd.exe или работать с открытым

10) Теперь в cmd.exe вы должны перейти в папку **openssl\bin**

11) После чего скопируйте и вставьте следующий код

> openssl sha1 -binary debug.txt > debug_sha.txt

12) Вы получите файл **debug_sha.txt**

13) Теперь опять скопируйте и вставьте следующий код

> openssl base64 -in debug_sha.txt > debug_base64.txt

14) Вы получите **debug_base64.txt** в папке **openssl\bin**

15) Откройте **debug_base64.txt**, он содержит Ваш валидный ключ.

---

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306009/facebook-android-generate-key-hash/12405323#12405323)

Comment: Мдааа. Я же русским языком написал. Что в первый раз работает. После выдает ошибку. Если первый раз работает то как тогда по вашему она работала без Ключа?.

Ясно ведь что я ключ получил